# Extracting substr and concat In Excel not working as it should

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have an excel file which has a date column in the format mm/dd/yyyy Like in this picture:

[image]

I want it in the format dd/mm/yyyy and i tried formatting the cells but they dont change. at last I chose to simply extract and concat the dates in a new column but it works for some cells while with others not.. this is the result:

[image]

As you can see sometimes it works and sometimes not. this is the formula I used (please bear in mind I am just starting out with excel and I have no clue of tricks or other methods) :

[image]

what is causing the faulty results in some of the cells ? TIA

Edit: Link for the data https://data.world/markbradbourne/rwfd-real-world-fake-data/workspace/file?filename=Call+Center.csv

Comment: Have you tried using the `Text To Columns`  from Data Tab, and select the Date --> MDY in the third step?

Comment: Your dates in Column E are not "real dates". Rather they are strings that look like dates. A better fix would be to change your procedure for entering those dates in the first place. Then simple formatting would work (or might not even be necessary).  What is your process for getting the dates into that column?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld This is dataset I got, I did not create it.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I will try it now !

Comment: Did you receive it as a text/csv file?  Or as an xlsx/xlsm file?  If the former, then you can IMPORT instead of OPENing the file.  If the latter, I'd use the Text-To-Columns wizard suggested by @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: @Armonia see i just updated the Answers with a gif. to show how its done using `Text-To-Columns` personally I will use it just because when working lot of data I will try to use less formatting as well as less formulas, if formula is not really required, like for such conversion I will certainly try to use Text To Columns. or may be VBA.

Answer (score 1):

If they are true date then can use-

```
=TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

If they are date format stored as text then can try-

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(A2),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

If you need to extract strings then concat and convert to dates then try-

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,4,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DATE formula and then format as you need
`=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(E2,4),MID(E2,4,2),LEFT(E2,2)),"dd/MM/YYYY")`

`DATE` formula takes Year, Month, Day as parameter - and converts that into a valid date.

`TEXT` then does the formatting for the output

Comment: When I try it on the first cell 10/29/2020 it gives me 10/05/2020 for some reason..

Comment: then you have to switch the second and the third argument - `=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(E2,4),LEFT(E2,2),MID(E2,4,2)),"dd/MM/YYYY")`

Comment: it worked for one cell then when I try to apply the formula to all of the column it gives me weird dates like 31/07/3934

Comment: then you need to provide your input data as table within the question - using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: please click in one cell of the timestamp column - what do you get in the editor row. Could it be that there are more data (e.g. time!) hidden by formatting?

Comment: just added the link to the table.. no there is no extra data, and the formulas are correct.. no clue why it happens

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should first try in using `Text To Columns` which in built in Excel, Under `Data Tab`, Grouped under `Data Tools`,

[image]

So just select those range, Goto `Data Tab` --> Click On `Text To Columns` --> Then select `Delimited` in the `First Step` --> `Next` --> `Next` as well in the `Second Step` --> and in the `Third Step` click on Date and change it to `MDY` and change the destination to adjacent cell and press `Finish`.

Since **Dates & Times** are stored as `Numbers` in `Excel` hence it will return you as numbers therefore you just need to format it as `dd/mm/yyyy` by pressing `CTRL 1` --> `Format Cells` dialog opens --> under `Number Tab` --> Click on `Custom` and type by removing the `General` --> dd/mm/yyyy.

---

Using `TEXTJOIN()` & `MID()` Functions, assuming you are using either **Excel 2019/2021 or MS365**

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",,MID(A2,{4,1,7},{2,2,4}))+0
```

---